# In a trading account what is the difference between margin and collateral?

Tags: stocks, margin, collateral

What does it mean when someone says a trade requires 10%, 100% or 150% margin?

What kind of calculations are required when you talk about margin and collateral?

What is a margin call and when does it happen?

Comment: Start with https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/margin.asp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word margin has several uses:

- Buying on margin refers to money borrowed.
- Initial margin requirement refers to the amount of collateral required to buy on margin (cash and/or marginable securities). It's 50% unless you're trading leveraged securities or your broker imposes stricter margin requirements.
- Margin maintenance requirement (MMR) refers to the amount of collateral you must have to maintain a margin position (25% for long positions and 30% for short positions unless you're trading leveraged securities or your broker imposes stricter margin requirements).  A margin call occurs if your account equity drops below your MMR.

Here's an article which explains [long and short margin calculations](https://thismatter.com/money/stocks/margin.htm).